# react material ui Textfield (type=number) validate 10 characters are existing

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, forms, material-ui

```
<TextField
    variant="outlined"
    required
    fullWidth
    id="accno"
    label="Main Account No"
    type="number"
    name="accno"
    //inputProps={{ className:"input-acc", pattern: "^.{0,10}$"}}
    autoComplete="accno"
    onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e)}
    onInput={(e)=>{ 
        e.target.value = Math.max(0, parseInt(e.target.value) ).toString().slice(0,10)
    }}
    min={10}
/>
```

react material ui Textfield (type=number) validate 10 characters are existing (mandatory).Otherwise i need form validation to show error. I tried regex pattern it wont work because this field type is number.

Answer (score 0):

The intuitive way is checking the length of value in `handleChange`

```
onChange={(e) => {
if(e.target.value.toString().length >= 10){
  //display error
 }
this.handleChange(e)
  }
}
```

You might also need to add the `error` property in TextField